# SwiftUI: How to share an in-memory file with ActivityViewController

Tags: swiftui, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a CSV file that I generate and can store in iCloud. This works well.

```
Button("\(Image(systemName: "folder"))\nExport")
{
    settings.showingExport = true
}
.fileExporter(isPresented: $settings.showingExport, document: CSVFile(initialText: reportText), contentType: UTType.commaSeparatedText, defaultFilename: reportName) { result in }
```

But I'd prefer to share this in-memory file with the ActivityViewController.

```
Button("\(Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up"))\nShare")
{
    showShareSheet = true
    shareSheetItems = [reportText]
}
.sheet(isPresented: $showShareSheet, content: {
    ActivityViewController(activityItems: $shareSheetItems, excludedActivityTypes: [])})
```

so I introduced this code from Hacking with Swift to create the CSV file:

```
struct CSVFile: FileDocument 
{
    static var readableContentTypes = [UTType.commaSeparatedText]
    static var writableContentTypes = [UTType.commaSeparatedText]

    // by default our document is empty
    var text = ""

    init(initialText: String = "")
    {
        text = initialText
    }

    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws
    {
        if let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents
        {
            text = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
        }
    }

    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper
    {
        let data = Data(text.utf8)
        return FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: data)
    }
}
```

Now when I create the CSV file is doesn't work.

```
Button("\(Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up"))\nShare")
{
    showShareSheet = true
    let csv = CSVFile(initialText: reportText)
    shareSheetItems = [csv]
}
.sheet(isPresented: $showShareSheet, content: {
    ActivityViewController(activityItems: $shareSheetItems, excludedActivityTypes: [])})
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Not enough info, but I think you have to confirm `CSVFile` to `NSItemProviderWriting/NSItemProviderReading` or prepare explicit NSItemProvider for document.

Comment: instead of `.sheet(isPresented: $showShareSheet,....` try using this other form 
`.sheet(item: $item, ....`

Comment: Just a question, what you mean exactly by "doesn't work" here? ActivityViewController not able to get hold of actual file?

Also if you are not mutating CSV on share sheet and also don't have any background changes on the CSV going on from somewhere else while share sheet is presented, then you probably don't need '@Binding' (or even '@State') for CSV in ActivityViewController i.e. activityItems.

You can remove that and keep it 'let' or use Binding.constant(value: shareSheetItems) while passing it to ActivityViewController.

Can you share code for ActivityViewController?

Comment: It doesn't share the in memory file. If I use the shareSheet with plain text it works, but if I try to put the text into an in memory file and share the file, then that doesn't work.

Comment: What were you hoping to gain by sharing an in-memory file?

Comment: I figured out why you can't share the CSVFile and wrote up how to do that but without saving it to disk I couldn't figure out how to share it as an actual file.  Just the `serializedRepresentation` or a `Data` with the contents.  I'm not seeing any benefit to doing that vs just the string.

Comment: Even saving it to a file you can't return the `FileWrapper` as the data but only the URL.

Comment: If I write the CSV out as text it gets copied out into the email/iMessage etc in full text. This would look much nicer if I simply enclosed it as a file. I don't need to have the file written to disk so I was hoping just to share the CSV file that I can export directly to the share panel.